# paypal, stripe - Prevent tampering data using express checkout

Tags: paypal, stripe-payments, payment

When using express checkout in both paypal/stripe/others, data is passed to the payment gateway(paypal/stripe) using javascript in the browser.

Since this happens in the browser using javascript, I am assuming it can be easily tampered so the end user can change price before sending data to payment gateway.

Any solutions on how to fix this ?

Comment: are you using this for web or mobile?

Comment: For Stripe, the amount is decided when you call the Create Charge API server-side. This can't be tampered unless you receive the amount from the client, which you should not (for the reasons you outlined)